# To display mat-chips inside the table component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using  `table` component in my project.In the 4th column i am displaying players names using `chips` as shown in below image:
[image]

**Here my issue is:** if i add 2 or more names in `players` string like this:

```
  players: 'Dwayne Jhonson,Tom cruise'
```

both the names are displaying in the same `chip` as shown in the above image,but i want each name to be displayed in `separate chips`.

Something like this:

[image]

Component code:
**HTML:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="players">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Players </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
       <mat-chip-list>
              <mat-chip>{{element.players}} </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  players: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, players: 'Dwayne Jhonson,Tom cruise'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, players: 'Kevin peterson, Brett Lee'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, players: 'Sachin Tendulakar, Yuvraj Sing'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'players'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehv7x4-9nnvrn?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If changing your model is an option try this.**

Declare`symbol` property to be a `string` array:

```
 export interface PeriodicElement {
  ....  
  symbol: string[];
}
```

and then change your data similarly to this:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: ['Dwayne Jhonson','Tom cruise']},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: ['Kevin peterson', 'Brett Lee']},
...
]
```

Finally on view, iterate through symbol elements to create multiple chips:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Players </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
       <mat-chip-list>
         <span *ngFor="let symbols of element.symbol">
              <mat-chip>{{symbols}} </mat-chip>
          </span>
          </mat-chip-list>
      </td>
  </ng-container>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-chips-array)

If changing your model **is not an option**, you need to create a function that will get symbol property as argument and will return a `string` array with the `strings` of the original string splited by `,`. Then in the view you have to iterate on this array to generate your chips.